# matplotlib, add legend for each line?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a code that looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [1, 2, 3]
x2 = [1, 2, 3]
y2 = [53, 2, 3]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.semilogx(x1, y1, marker='o', label='Phase Envelope')
ax.semilogx(x2, y2, marker=',', label='Isotherm, 200 C')

plt.show()
```

I want to add legend to each line, but for some reason label = '...' argument does not work. I thought this was the code that adds legend. What should I do?

Comment: Add `plt.legend()` to your code.

Comment: Matplotlib is constantly trying to improve [its documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/tutorials/index.html#introductory). Hence it would be interesting to know at which point it would have helped you to read about adding `plt.legend()` to create a legend, such that you would not have needed to ask this question.